# 連続投票とは何ですか？

Tags: サポート, よくある質問の案, 投票

ある日突然、私の信用度がガクッと下がってしまいました。よく分からなかったのでプロフィールページの「信用度」タブから原因を探ろうとしました。

タブを見てみたところ、「取り消し」という名前の普段見かけないイベントがありました。普段質問タイトルが書かれているところには「連続投票が取り消されました」と書かれています。

[image: すぐ上で説明されているイベントのスクリーンショットです。]

- このイベントはどういう意味ですか？　何が起こったのでしょうか？
- 何かしら自分が悪いことをしたのでしょうか？
- なぜ信用度を失ったのでしょうか？
- 失った分を取り戻す方法はありますか？

[←よくある質問の目次に戻る](/q/1484)

<sub>※この質問は Meta Stack Exchange の ["What is serial voting and how does it affect me?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/) を元にしたものです。</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

これは、不正な投票が取り消されたことによる現象です。サイトのヘルプにも以下のページに記述があります。

- [信用度ページに「連続投票が取り消されました」という信用度の変更があるのはなぜですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed)

この回答では、不正投票とそれにまつわる処置についてより詳しく説明します。

### 不正投票とは？

[プラス投票](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)や[マイナス投票](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)をすべきかどうかに関わらず無差別に投票することを、不正投票と呼びます。よくあるのは、ひとりのユーザーがあるユーザーの投稿を短時間の間にたくさん投票し続けるものです。このような行為は通常のものではなく、システムとしても許容できるものではありません。

特定のユーザーに対して大量の投票行為が行われたときや、単に怪しい行為が行われたとき、モデレーターや Stack Exchange のスタッフによってその詳細が調べられます。不正投票が確認された場合、それに関わっていたユーザーに対して処置が行われます。

### 連続プラス投票が起こるのはどんなとき？

自分の投稿に対して急にたくさんプラス投票された場合、大抵はシンプルにあなたへたくさん信用度を与えたくなったユーザーがいます。おそらくそのユーザーはあなたの投稿がとても参考になり、あなたの投稿を無差別にプラス投票することによって信用度を増やそうとしたのでしょう。このような場合、[懸賞](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)の仕組みを使うのが適切な方法です。

また、時々、ふたりのユーザーが示し合わせてお互いの投稿をプラス投票しあっていることもあります。あるいは、ひとりのユーザーが[多重アカウント](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312819/)を作って信用度を不正に増やそうとしている場合もあります。このようなことをした場合、アカウント停止に繋がる可能性が非常に高いです。

### 連続マイナス投票が起こるのはどんなとき？

急にたくさんマイナス投票されるようになった場合、大抵は誰かあなたの投稿に納得できなかったユーザーがいます。おそらく、あなたのプロフィールページから投稿を無差別にマイナス投票していったのでしょう。また時には、悪ふざけとしてこのようなことを行うユーザーが現れることもあります。

### 不正投票の対象になっていると思ったとき、どうすればよいでしょうか？

もし今現在不正投票が行われている場合、気にする必要はありません。まずは何もせず、投票が起こってから最低 24 時間待ってみてください。多くの場合、システムが自動的に不正投票を検知し、24 時間以内にそれらを取り消します。この 24 時間が経過するまでの間は、何もする必要はありません。たとえばモデレーターに通報したとしてもモデレーターも何もできず、ただ自動検知スクリプトが走るのを一緒に待つのみになります（特定のユーザーについてスクリプトを走らせるようなことは、モデレーターでさえも行えません）。

もし既に上記の 24 時間が過ぎていて、かつ不正投票の疑惑がある投票が取り消されていない場合、「モデレーターによる対応が必要です」として自分の投稿のひとつを通報し、何が起こっているかを詳しく説明するようにしてみてください。

また、不正投票の疑いについてメタで質問を投稿しないことを、強く推奨します。不正の調査は非公開で行われますし、将来的にも明かされません。そして一般のユーザーが不正投票に対して行えることはありません。もしメタで投稿してしまうと、誰が投票しているのか興味が集まり、不適切な推測を呼んでしまいます。そういった推測は火に油を注いでしまい、更なる投票を招いてしまいがちです。

合わせて読みたい：

- 下の方に書かれている「不正投票について自分の投稿をモデレーターに通報した場合、調査はどのように進みますか？」の部分
- [What should you do if you're serial downvoted & it isn't automatically reversed within 24 hours?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/212339/341401)

### システムはどのように不正投票を検知しますか？

毎日 UTC 3 時頃に不正投票検知スクリプトが実行され、不正の兆候があるかチェックされます。基本的には他のユーザーに何回も投票しているユーザーがチェックされます。ここでのしきい値は時間に対してある程度低く設定されています（正確な仕組みは公開されていません）。システムが兆候を見つけた場合、影響を受けたユーザーに対するそのユーザーの投票は取り消され、影響を受けた側のユーザーの信用度履歴には「連続投票が取り消されました」というイベントが追加されます。

取り消される信用度の量は色々ありえます。プラス投票にせよマイナス投票にせよすべての投票がいっしょくたにまとめられて取り消されます。もしユーザーの信用度変化が上限に達しており、投票を取り消したとしてもその日の信用度変化に影響を与えない場合、変化した信用度の量は空白として表示されます。

### 削除された投稿についても不正投票が検知されますか？

はい。もし連続投票が起こったあと投稿が削除された場合についても、不正が検知された場合は投票が取り消されます。

一般のユーザーがこの挙動に気付くのはなかなか難しいですが、たとえばスパムアカウントによるスパム回答をまとめて一気にマイナス投票した場合に気付ける場合があります。そういったスパム回答は通報されそのうち削除されてしまう訳ですが、その後しばらくして自分の信用度履歴に「+1 マイナス票の取り消し済み」という項目が並ぶようになります（[例](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7493744#7493744)）。

### なぜ元の信用度のままでは駄目なのですか？

連続投票は想定されている挙動ではなく許されていないため、増減した信用度は取り消されます。連続投票はシステムによってすべて無効化され、したがってそれによる信用度変化も無効化されます。連続投票によって一時的に増えてしまった信用度を取り戻す唯一の方法は、そのままサイト上での投稿を続けて、正規のプラス投票をもらうことです。

### プロフィールに表示される取り消しについて気にするべきですか？

いえ、気にする必要はありません。これは単に信用度の変化を示しているだけです。結局のところ、自分と関係ない他のユーザーの行動をコントロールすることはできません。自分自身に対して不正投票を行っている人は稀ですし、もしそのようなことをしていたのであれば警告を受けていたりアカウント停止されていたりするはずです。いかなる場合においても、自分のアカウントや他者のアカウントの信用度履歴にある取り消しについて気にする必要はありません。

### 不正投票について自分の投稿をモデレーターに通報した場合、調査はどのように進みますか？

モデレーターは、不正投票の兆候を特定するための情報を幾らか閲覧することができます（ただし投票の完全な情報は公開されていません）。モデレーターが不正投票の通報を受け取った場合、この情報を使って調査が始まります。

通報を受け取ったモデレーターが不正投票やその疑惑を見つけた場合、モデレーターは Stack Exchange の社員に報告します。Stack Exchange の社員のみが完全な記録を閲覧でき、手動で投票を取り消すことができます。作業待ちの報告の数が多いと、社員によって問題が完全に解決されるまでに時間がかかることがあります。社員による処理は数日から数週間の内に終わるように善処されますが、数ヶ月以上かかる場合もあります。

モデレーターに通報した場合、その通報が役に立ったのか却下されたのかの情報は見れますが、通報や不正投票についてそれ以外の情報を直接の返信として得ることはありません。多くの場合「役に立った」「却下」のそれぞれは社員に報告したかしなかったかと連動していますが、そうでない場合もあります。通報が何かしら意味のあるものだと判断されれば「役に立った」として処理されますが、必ずしもそれが不正投票であると考えたとは限りません。モデレーターは、通報を破棄する際に短い返信をテキストで書くことがありますが、必須ではありません。

不正投票を通報してもその後の処理が進んでいるかどうかについて情報が得られないのは、いささかもどかしいものです。最終的にすべての処理が終わるまでは状況の更新や報告を得ることができません。間接的な情報としては、投票の無効化が起こっていることを確認できたり、信用度ログで投票の取り消しを確認できたりはします。場合によっては「不正な投票」によってユーザーのアカウントが停止されているのを確認できることもありますが、これは毎回起こるようなことではありません。これらより詳しい情報は得ることができません。

### この話題について他に知っておくべきことはありますか？

- **取り消しによって信用度は再計算されます。**
  連続投票が取り消された場合、その連続投票があったすべての日について信用度が再計算され、連続投票は起きなかったものとして扱われます。もし信用度上限に当たって得られなかった信用度があった場合、このタイミングで得ることができ、本来得られるべきだった信用度を復活させます。またこの際、信用度履歴の表示も[修正されます](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352454#comment493984_352454)。
  （ごく稀に、信用度が[すぐには再計算されないことがあります](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24867)。これによって一時的に信用度の合計値が正しくなくなりますが、次信用度が再計算された際に修正され、連続投票と信用度上限によって失った信用度は戻ってきます。信用度が再計算されるのは、多くの場合、何かしらの投稿が削除されたり削除が取り消されたりしたときです。）
- **投票が取り消された場合、再度投票できます。**
  検知スクリプトによって取り消された投票は、その投票をしたのと同じユーザーによって再度投票できます。ただし再び連続投票を行った場合は同じように取り消されます。
- **何かしら自動的なアカウント停止や通知はありません。**
  現在のところ、連続投票を検知するスクリプトは投票を取り消すのみで、信用度履歴に影響を及ぼす以外の影響を及ぼしません。連続投票したユーザーを自動的に BAN することはしませんし、マイナス投票の連続だった場合の「+1 マイナス票の取り消し済み」という通知以外の通知を送ることはありません。
  システムを何回も悪用し投票取り消しを引き起こすことはアカウント停止に繋がりますが、そのような停止を行う手順はすべて手動で行われます。連続投票関係の通報が自動的になされることもありません。ただしモデレーターは、何回も攻撃を繰り返すユーザーに対処するためにいくつかの統計情報を見ることができます。もしあなたが短い期間に何回も連続投票の対象になってしまったら、「モデレーターによる対応が必要です」として自分の投稿のどれかを自分で通報し、モデレーターが調査しやすいよう状況を説明する文章を送信してみてください。